# Debugging Backbone.js: rendering after collection fetch()

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to do basic render() after fetch() on collection (Backbone 0.9.2):

```
var ProjectListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#container'),
        initialize: function () {
            this.collection = new ProjectsCollection();
            this.collection.bind("change", _.bind(this.render, this));
            this.collection.fetch({ success: function () { console.log("collection fetched"); } });
            ...
             }, 
        render: function () {
            console.log("rendered");
            ...
```

Creating new View instance prints out:

```
    collection fetched
```

So the render() never gets called after fetch(). What am I doing wrong here? There are no exceptions present.

Any tips how to debug these sort of things in backbone?

Ps.
It seems that this feature is poorly documented given the number of questions on SO.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch):

> **fetch** `collection.fetch([options])`
>
> Fetch the default set of models for this collection from the server, resetting the collection when they arrive. [...] When the model data returns from the server, the collection will reset.

And what does `reset` do? [`reset`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) does this:

> **reset** `collection.reset(models, [options])`
>
> [...] Use **reset** to replace a collection with a new list of models (or attribute hashes), triggering a single `"reset"` event at the end.

So `fetch` calls `reset` to update the collection's models and `reset` triggers a `"reset"` event, not a `"change"` event. None of the models have changed and a collection's `"change"` events come from its models.

You should have `render` bound to `"reset"`:

```
initialize: function () {
    this.collection = new ProjectsCollection();
    this.collection.bind("reset", _.bind(this.render, this));
    this.collection.fetch(...);
}
```

If you want to listen for `"change"` events on the contained models then you can bind a `"change"` handler to the collection [since](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection):

> You can bind `"change"` events to be notified when any model in the collection has been modified,
>   [...]
>   Any event that is triggered on a model in a collection will also be triggered on the collection directly, for convenience.

The collection will also generate `"add"` and `"remove"` events as the collection itself changes.

---

Newer versions of Backbone no longer reset collections during [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch):

> When the model data returns from the server, it uses *set* to (intelligently) merge the fetched models, unless you pass `{reset: true}`, in which case the collection will be (efficiently) *reset*.

And [`set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-set):

> [...] performs a "smart" update of the collection with the passed list of models. If a model in the list isn't yet in the collection it will be added; if the model is already in the collection its attributes will be merged; and if the collection contains any models that aren't present in the list, they'll be removed. All of the appropriate `"add"`, `"remove"`, and `"change"` events are fired as this happens

So with newer versions of Backbone you'll want to list for the `"add"`, `"remove"`, and `"change"` events (which a collection based view should be listening for anyway); you could also use `{reset: true}` on the initial `fetch` and listen to `"reset"` as well. I'd recommend the following approach for collection based views:

1. Listen to `"add"` and handle that event with a callback that simply adds one item to the view, don't throw everything away and re-render.
2. Listen to `"remvoe"` and handle that event with a callback that only removes the newly removed model.
3. Listen to `"change"` and handle that with a callback that replaces (or updates) the appropriate item.
4. Listen to `"reset"` and bind that to `render`. Then pass `{reset: true}` to the collection's initial `fetch` call.

That will trap the important events and the collection-view will do the minimal amount of work to handle each one. Of course, this strategy isn't applicable to all situations but I think it is a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you for thorough answer, hopefully this will be useful to others. PS. Are there other resources you could recommend besides the official docs?

Comment: @Fdr: I read the docs and the source code for reference. And after 15+ years, all the frameworks look pretty much the same.

Comment: I guess so. These events in backbone are bit tripping: "reset" is raised for collections, but there is no similarity when doing model.fetch() (which causes "change" to be emitted). Weak api design?

Comment: But then how would you differentiate between a change on the collection and a change on one of the models? Hence add, remove. And reset events. Your views/templates should be able to handle empty models so a change event should be enough, you can patch in a fetched event if necessary by overriding `fetch`.

Comment: My point was that when names are identical then one expect same kind of behavior. If behavior differs so should names: in case of model.fecth() better naming would be model.load() or model.update()

Comment: You can now (1.0) use 
this.listenTo(this.collection, "sync", this.render);

Answer (score 8):

This changed in 1.0

http://backbonejs.org/#changelog

"If you'd like to continue using "reset", pass {reset: true}."

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so until some one can explain why binding didn't work, I used following workaround:

```
   initialize: function () {
            var self = this;
            this.collection = new ProjectsCollection();
            this.collection.fetch({ success: function () { self.render(); } });
```